# Correlating RISAT and Sentinel-1 data

Tags: sentinel-1

The Sentinal-1 dataset's metadata contain the following values:

```
range_spacing, azimuth_spacing, incidence_near, incidence_far.
```

1. What are corresponding names for these values in the RISAT Band_Meta.txt file? It does not have range and azimuth spacings and contains only one incidence angle.
2. Which point in the image has this incidence angle?
3. For my work, I need the incidence angle at every pixel in the image, how do I get it in case of RISAT (for Sentinel, I could do the math using near and far incidence angles and get it but can't do it here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your queries one by one :

1) For range and azimuth spacing : Look at **OutputLineSpacing** and **OutputPixelSpacing** specified within the BAND_META.txt file. As you might be aware, the **OutputLineSpacing** corresponds to azimuth_spacing and **OutputPixelSpacing** corresponds to range_spacing.

2)**The incidence angle given in the BAND_META file is that of the scene centre.**

3)For incidence angle, you can try two different approaches :

a) There are grid files available with the product with name **productname_grd.txt**, from there you can find out the incidence angle at each point by interpolation. The format of this grid file is explained in the product format, the link of which I am mentioning here :
[RISAT-1 Product Format](https://nrsc.gov.in/sites/all/pdf/format3.pdf)

b) You will be able to find a **product.xml** file alongwith your product. Open that file, where you will find **incidenceAnglenear range** and **incidence angle farrange** fields. Utilising these fields, apply interpolation accordingly to get the incidence angle at each pixel.

The first approach utilising grid files will be more accurate.

All the best!!!!!!!!